# avoid duplication of options using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 5 rows. each rows first column is select tag.

```
 <table>
<tr>
    <th>fruits</th>
    <th>count</th>
   </tr>
<tr>
    <td><select>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="1">apple</option>
         <option value="2">orange</option>
         <option value="3">banana</option>
         <option value="4">grapes</option>
         <option value="5">strawberry</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><select>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="1">apple</option>
         <option value="2">orange</option>
         <option value="3">banana</option>
         <option value="4">grapes</option>
         <option value="5">strawberry</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><select>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="1">apple</option>
         <option value="2">orange</option>
         <option value="3">banana</option>
         <option value="4">grapes</option>
         <option value="5">strawberry</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><select>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="1">apple</option>
         <option value="2">orange</option>
         <option value="3">banana</option>
         <option value="4">grapes</option>
         <option value="5">strawberry</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><select>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="1">apple</option>
         <option value="2">orange</option>
         <option value="3">banana</option>
         <option value="4">grapes</option>
         <option value="5">strawberry</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Now I want to prevent select the same option more than one time will alert the message about duplication and retuned to --select--.
How it is write using jquery?

Comment: have you tried anything so far ? if yes please show code so we can help.

Comment: I'd consider a templating plugin for something like this

Comment: Another way could be to use a multiple select but you seem not to wan't this option. Else you can take a look at a library like http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/ (I am not very fan of select2 but it is another option)

Comment: Good idea, one multiselect would be the way to go. Just do one `<select multiple>......</select>` - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: I voted up for Milind Anantwar's answer if multiple select is not an option

Comment: a hacky solution is http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6yqfgsjg/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('table select').change(function() {
    if ($('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected').length > 1) {
        alert('option is already selected');
        $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());   
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uzvy75pk/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var current = $(this).val();
  var count = 0;
  $('select').each(function() {
     if (current == $(this).val()) {
        count++;
     }
  })
  if (count > 1) {
     alert('Already Selected');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach can be as below - (still can be refined to keep the order of items)

```js
var $selects = $('select');

$selects.on('change', function() {
  var value = this.value,
    $this = $(this),
    $prev = $this.data('prev'),
    $selected = $this.find(':selected');

  if ($prev) {
    $this.removeData('prev');
    $selects.not(this).append(function() {
      return $prev.clone();
    })
  }

  if (value) {
    $selects.not(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').remove();
    $this.data('prev', $selected);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>fruits</th>
    <th>count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="1">apple</option>
        <option value="2">orange</option>
        <option value="3">banana</option>
        <option value="4">grapes</option>
        <option value="5">strawberry</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="1">apple</option>
        <option value="2">orange</option>
        <option value="3">banana</option>
        <option value="4">grapes</option>
        <option value="5">strawberry</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="1">apple</option>
        <option value="2">orange</option>
        <option value="3">banana</option>
        <option value="4">grapes</option>
        <option value="5">strawberry</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="1">apple</option>
        <option value="2">orange</option>
        <option value="3">banana</option>
        <option value="4">grapes</option>
        <option value="5">strawberry</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="1">apple</option>
        <option value="2">orange</option>
        <option value="3">banana</option>
        <option value="4">grapes</option>
        <option value="5">strawberry</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```